# whats the logical explanation of [0]?

Tags: javascript

Inside the forwardslash : i understand the logic behind the *while*(i think, but it      doesnt hurt to be explained by an expert :) ), the deleteList.length > 0 too but i dont get why the [0].  this throws me off. because I assimilate this to an erray and as i add my todo list i believe that *deleteList becomes and errays when i add todos*. but wouldnt [0] just delete the li(todos) in the index 0 of the li errays? the button works it deletes all the li elements i create, but i want to understand the logic behind this.
thank you in advance. also if you know of other easier way of writing it.

```
const deleteAll = function() {
  var ulList = document.getElementById('list');
  var deleteList = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  /////
  while (deleteList.length > 0) {
    ulList.removeChild(deleteList[0]);
  }
  ////
  console.log(deleteList);
};
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Then take the [tour].

Comment: It deletes the first element in the array, as you suspected, but it does it repeatedly as the loop iterates. Each time there's a new first element.

Comment: The deleteList is an array. All the arrays has an index starting by '0', so if you have 10 elements in the array, the index are 0 to 9. What your code is doing is iterating over the deleteList array and deleting the first element (deleteList[0]). Then the length of the array is reduced (for example from 10 to 9) until it is '0'.